# While am I a still getting a NullPointerException although this loop (readLines) does not add a null entry?

Tags: java

I am getting a NullPointerException error in my code, I have narrowed it down to be this piece of code that is causing the exception

```
AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);
```

I had thought that the value mText would be retrived from futher up the code using this code :

```
BufferedReader br = null;
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        while ((mText = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
                            System.out.println(mText);
                            list.add(mText);
                        }
```

But I still get the null error, I thought the value mText would come from the above code and be used but this doesn't seem to be happening, why is this, the whole code is below

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrintText implements Printable {

     private List<String> list;

    // Below the code will allow the user to select a file and then print out the contents of the file
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new PrintText();
    }

    public PrintText() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }

                    //selects the file
                    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    String filename = file.getName();
                    //System.out.println("You have selected: " + filename);  testing to see if file seleected was right
                    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

                    //Reads contents of file into terminal 
                    //FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename");
                    // FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/Documents/" + "filename")); 

                    BufferedReader br = null;
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            list.add(line);
                        }

                        printer();
                    } catch (IOException exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            br.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                    //fr.close(); 
                }
            });
    }
    //private static final String mText = 
    //    "This is a test to see if this text will be printed "; //This works perfectly fine
    //AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);
    /**
     * Print a single page containing some sample text.
     */
    public void printer() {

        /* Get the representation of the current printer and 
         * the current print job.
         */
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        /* Build a book containing pairs of page painters (Printables)
         * and PageFormats. This example has a single page containing
         * text.
         */
        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(this, new PageFormat());
        /* Set the object to be printed (the Book) into the PrinterJob.
         * Doing this before bringing up the print dialog allows the
         * print dialog to correctly display the page range to be printed
         * and to dissallow any print settings not appropriate for the
         * pages to be printed.
         */
        printerJob.setPageable(book);
        /* Show the print dialog to the user. This is an optional step
         * and need not be done if the application wants to perform
         * 'quiet' printing. If the user cancels the print dialog then false
         * is returned. If true is returned we go ahead and print.
         */
        boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                printerJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException exception) {
                System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print a page of text.
     */
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pageIndex) {

        System.out.println("About to obtain an attributed string, list=" + list);
        AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(list);
        // etc
        /* We'll assume that Jav2D is available.
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        /* Move the origin from the corner of the Paper to the corner
         * of the imageable area.
         */
        g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());
        /* Set the text color.
         */
        g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
        /* Use a LineBreakMeasurer instance to break our text into
         * lines that fit the imageable area of the page.
         */
        Point2D.Float pen = new Point2D.Float();
        AttributedCharacterIterator charIterator = mStyledText.getIterator();
        LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIterator, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
        float wrappingWidth = (float) format.getImageableWidth();
        while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
            TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);
            pen.y += layout.getAscent();
            float dx = layout.isLeftToRight() ? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
            layout.draw(g2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
            pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.AttributedString.<init>(AttributedString.java:127)
    at PrintText.print(PrintText.java:109)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(RasterPrinterJob.java:1973)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1461)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1277)
    at PrintText.printer(PrintText.java:97)
    at PrintText$1.run(PrintText.java:51)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way this loop can exit:

```
while ((mText = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(mText);
    list.add(mText);
}
```

is when `mText` is null. So for sure, `mText` must be null later on in the code.

You are able to access the lines of the file by using the `list` variable, but you need to either pass it as a parameter to your method:

```
public void printer(List<String> list) {
    // etc...
}
```

Or make it a field of your class so that it is visible to the other methods in the class.

```
public class PrintText implements Printable {
    private List<String> list;
    // etc..
}
```

---

In addition to reduce the risk of similar errors in the future I recommend that you delete the static field `mText` and instead use a local variable inside the method:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    list.add(line);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i have also tried it with the list variable, but i then get a compiler error saying cannot find symbol variable List

Comment: @user1924104: read on variable *scope*. The list variable is only visible within the block that it was declared in, and so it is likely not visible where you are trying to use it. Solution: declare it in a higher block or in the class.

Comment: Seeing that you simply want to read the whole file, I also recommend replacing your `ArrayList` with a `StringBuilder` and using `StringBuilder.append(mText)` to populate it (also including an extra line separator if needed). Later on, you can pass the result of `StringBuilder.toString()` to the `AttributedString` constructor.

Comment: @user1924104: Why public? Do you want this list to be accessible from outside the class? If so, use a getter. Public fields are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Ok, changed to private, edited the main question showing the code atm, is this right, i am not sure what you mean in your answer about making it a field of a class

Comment: @user1924104: no it is wrong. The variables should most definitely not be static.

Comment: Ok i am starting to understand the original answer, thank you

Comment: Thank you, i think i have done all that you suggested however now on compliing i get the error : no suitable constructor found for AttributedString(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)

Comment: @user1924104: That's because you are passing the entire list of strings instead of a single string. Have you ever written a program before? I think you need to go read a basic tutorial before attempting something like this.

Comment: Ok, how can i pass the entire list ? and no this is my first ever program in any language i have written

Comment: @user1924104: Normally the first program someone writes is "Hello World" or something similar. I'm sorry to say it, but you're biting off more than you can chew. There's little chance of you being able to write this program correctly without first getting a basic understanding of how Java works.

Comment: sorry i have written hello world, but nothing on this scale, i understand it is a big ask for a first timer, is there anyway to make this code work, as this is pretty much all i need to do

Comment: would i have to convert the array of strings to a string after the loop on would i have to modify my code to accept the list of strings instead of just one string